# How to make crispy chicken wings like KFC?

Tags: chicken-wings

I want to prepare Chicken wings more crispy without using micro oven. Can anyone tell me how to prepare it?

Comment: I guess you seek for a more sophisticated answer as: "bread it and deep fry it". But i don't know what else to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Some general tips.

Use a deep fryer ( or a large cast iron skillet with less oil; have a proper thermometer to help you keep the oil temperature stable (250°-300°F)

Don't overcrowd the skillet, 2, 3 pieces max per batch.

The chicken should not be too cold when cooking it (because the time the inside will be cooked, the outside will be burned) get it out of the fridge a little bit in advance.

Prepare a simple egg-wash and a mix of flour and spices and salt/pepper (experiment to find what you like)

Put the chicken pieces in the egg-wash, transfer to the flour mix, coat well, remove excess flour ; then back again in the egg-wash and again in the flour mix.

Then you can let it rest a little while (10 minutes) while the oil gets hot.

Fry the chicken 10, 12 minutes until the exterior gets to a nice golden color; take one piece out and check the doneness (temperature and/or visual clues).

Transfer to paper to absorb some of the excess oil.

eat it.

Comment: Great advice but I would suggest you first dip the wings in the flour before the egg wash.

Comment: I think this will help. I'll surely try it out. Can you suggest me the spices used other than Garlic Salt, Black Pepper to get a better taste?